# Are questions of this sort allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

So I was tempted to ask this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3446764/) (after some slight physics edits - see comment section) in physics stack exchange and would like the wisdom of the community if it would be closed or not?

### Why I'm asking Meta first

1. Crossposts between physics and math stack exchange are discouraged.
2. It does involve the use of a math formula. Therefore understanding the question would (partially) depend on that.
3. The question is possibly (indirectly) about an open problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your [specific question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3446764/11127) is fundamentally a physics question (in the area of statistical physics) rather than a math question. It should be migrated to Phys.SE rather than being crossposted.

Comment: Raised a flag. Thanks :)

Comment: It's now [migrated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515541/2451).